# Execute java project with node-jre module

Tags: java, node.js

I am developing a node.js application where I need to execute java code.

I am using de node-jre module (https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-jre).

The example in this web (Hello.class) is running correctly with this code and compilling de Hello class by console with *javac Hello.java*:

```
    var output = jre.spawnSync(  // call synchronously 
    ['java'],                // add the relative directory 'java' to the class-path 
    'Hello',                 // call main routine in class 'Hello' 
    ['World'],               // pass 'World' as only parameter 
    { encoding: 'utf8' }     // encode output as string 
  ).stdout.trim();
```

The problem is when I tried to execute my java project (developed with eclipse). The documentation say that in this directory 'java' search inside jar files. So, it was the first thing I tried: to export the proyect to jar, but it does not work.

So, how can I execute a complete project (with only one main class)?, I think it is important to say that the project use external libraries.

The META-INF/MANIFEST.MF inside jar looks like:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Class-Path: .
Main-Class: com.packagename.example1.ClassName

Name: org/apache/oro
Specification-Title: Jakarta ORO
Implementation-Title: org.apache.oro
Implementation-Version: 2.0.8 2003-12-28 11:00:13
Specification-Version: 2.0.8
Specification-Vendor: Apache Software Foundation
Implementation-Vendor: Apache Software Foundation
```

So, my code is:

```
 var output = jre.spawnSync(  // call synchronously 
    ['java'],                // add the relative directory 'java' to the class-path 
    'ClassName',                 // call main routine in class 'Hello' 
    ['World'],               // pass 'World' as only parameter 
    { encoding: 'utf8' }     // encode output as string 
  ).stdout.trim();
```

And I tried also with:

```
 var output = jre.spawnSync(  // call synchronously 
        ['java'],                // add the relative directory 'java' to the class-path 
        'com.packagename.example1.ClassName',                 // call main routine in class 'Hello' 
        ['World'],               // pass 'World' as only parameter 
        { encoding: 'utf8' }     // encode output as string 
      ).stdout.trim();
```

'java' was the folder that I have in node in the same level that *server.js*

Comment: What does your Manifest file look like inside the jar? Is the main class declared? The classpath?

Comment: In the Manifiest: `Manifest-Version: 1.0
Class-Path: .
Main-Class: com.package.example1.ClassName`

Comment: You can edit your post if needs be to add details. Also please check how to create a MCVE: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve It will help anyone seeing the post to understand and reproduce your issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that I just put the directory where the .jar file is and the correct way was to put the complete path to the jar file: **java/Nameofjarfile.jar**

```
 var output = jre.spawnSync(  // call synchronously 
        ['java/Nameofjarfile.jar'],                // add the relative directory 'java' to the class-path 
        'com.packagename.example1.ClassName',                 // call main routine in class 'Hello' 
        ['World'],               // pass 'World' as only parameter 
        { encoding: 'utf8' }     // encode output as string 
      ).stdout.trim();
```